# Differentiating widths of a string in Presto (zero-width characters)

Tags: presto

I'd like to compare string lengths in bytes of a field, because the field could have some zero-width characters in it.

The [Binary](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/binary.html) functions seem most relevant, but it seems they all expect length-one input and I can't figure any way to split out the string to individual rows.

e.g.

```
select from_hex('abc')
```

gives error

> invalid input length 3

And I can't "split on nothing" to convert this to 3 rows (`a`, `b`, `c` separately):

```
select split('abc', '')
```

> The delimiter may not be the empty string

In R, I'm accustomed to the `nchar` function where I can specify `type = 'bytes'` (count by bytes), `'chars'` (matches Presto's `length` from what I've seen), or `'width'` (zero-width characters don't count -- the visible width of the string), and where `strsplit('abc', NULL)` or `strsplit('abc', '')` give `list(c('a', 'b', 'c'))`.

I'm not sure I can copy-paste a string with a zero-width character here so here's R code to create one:

```
rawToChar(as.raw(c(0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6F, 0xe2, 0x80, 0x8d)))
```

with Presto `length` output:

```
select length('hello‍')
```

In R, I can get three different widths of this string:

```
sapply(c('width', 'chars', 'bytes'), x = 'hello‍')
# width chars bytes 
#     5     6     8
```

Is there any way to replicate this in Presto?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in Presto?

Comment: @piotrfindeisen I think a minimal version would be to get the `width` of 5 (i.e. exclusive of zero-width characters)

Comment: In other words, you have a `varchar` and you want to count it's length (in characters) excluding zero-width characters, correct?

Comment: more specifically its the printing width: "`type = "width"` gives (an approximation to) the number of columns used in printing each element in a terminal font, taking into account double-width, zero-width and ‘composing’ characters." https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/nchar

Comment: Hm.. looks impossible today. Would you like to create an issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/?

Comment: sure... was 50/50 asking here vs filing first... wasn't quite convinced the binary functions can't be pressed into service

Comment: Sure, understood!